# Should one refer to the title of an article or to the title of the magazine when the author is unknown (MLA/APA)

Tags: citations

I think the title is quite clear.

If the author of an article is unknwon, should one refer to the title of the article, or to the magazine itself? The same goes for electronic sources.

Let's say this is my source.

> “An Interview with Susan Bassnett.” *Channel View Publications Blog*.
>   Channel View Publications. n.d. Web. 5 dec. 2013.

Would I refer (inline) like so:

> Bassnet states that ... ("An Interview with Susan Bassnett").

or like so

> Bassnett states that ... (*Channel View Publications Blog*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *MLA Style Manual*, which is excerpted on many sites (such as [the Williams College Library homepage](http://library.williams.edu/citing/styles/mla.php)), they recommend using a partial title as the citation.

So, in the case above, you'd probably write

> Bassnett states that . . . ("Interview" 201).

unless you have multiple works with unknown authors whose title starts with "Interview." Then you'd need more of the title to distinguish it:

> Bassnett states that . . . ("Interview with Susan Bassnett" 201). Smith responds by claiming . . . ("Interview with Robert Smith" 12).

Comment: And what would one do if the author is unknown *and* the titles of multiple works are identical?

Answer (score 1):

The [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/03/) says for APA

> Unknown Author: If the work does not have an author, cite the source by its title in the signal phrase or use the first word or two in the parentheses. Titles of books and reports are italicized or underlined; titles of articles, chapters, and web pages are in quotation marks.

So ideally you would write:

> In "An Interview with Susan Bassnet" (2001) Bassnet said ...

But you could write:

> Some silly statement ("Interview," 2001)

I think if you have two sources from 2001 with no author, you would use 2001a and 2001b, so you would not need to change the short title.